# Why do we call excerpts of writing "passages"?

Tags: etymology

My guess is that it has to do with the physical process of scanning, moving your eyes over the words, but I can't find any confirmation.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if there is some biblical connection.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is of a piece of writing that connects the previous to the next one, as in a sequence of passages:

[passage](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=passage) (n.) :

> - early 13c., "a road, passage;" late 13c., "action of passing," from Old French passage "mountain pass, passage" (11c.), from passer "to go by" (see pass (v.)). Meaning "corridor in a building" first recorded 1610s. ***Meaning "a portion of writing" is from 1610s, of music, from 1670s.***

(Etymonline)

From [The Tryal of Henry Sacheverell Before the House of Peers for High Crimes and ...](https://books.google.it/books?id=zfNaAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA275&dq=%22read%20a%20passage%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjpzZHZtOLTAhULB8AKHVESB5MQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=%22read%20a%20passage%22&f=false) (1710)

> - would therefore beg Leave ***to read a Passage*** where he explains himself, and plainly declares what his Thoughts are concerning the Indulgence granted by Law : ***This Passage is in the twentieth Page,***  where speaking of some wholesome Severities us'd in former Reigns, he adds, I would not here be misunderstood, as if I ...